Blade setting with mulching plug inserted
I have a mountfield 1538 ride on mower. What setting should I have the blades at when I have a mulching plug inserted?

If the operator's manual makes no specific recommendation, whatever height you want to mow at. Higher tends to make a healthier lawn, in general (because taller grass goes with deeper roots.)
If you have let the lawn get much taller than your preferred cut height, either don't mulch, or raise to near-but-below the height it has grown to and then lower on successive mowings; so as not to make excessive amounts of mulch on any one mowing.
